# How to fix an indentation error in the following code?

Tags: python, syntax, indentation, abaqus

I wrote the following code to extract some results from Abaqus. I get an indentation error when I run the code. I have 19 simulation and I want to use this code to extract the results that I want. I have tried to fix it, but I couldn't. Can anyone help me and tell me what the problem is?

```
import os
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from viewerModules import *
from driverUtils import executeOnCaeStartup

# Function to create a new folder if it does not exist
def create_folder_if_not_exists(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

# Loop to process each ODB file
for i in range(1, 20):
    odb_path = 'D:/Majid/Solder Project-LG/2023-05-25-Final simulation/Warpage file number #5/19 location-New/Load -20%/'
    odb_filename = '0i.odb'
    odb_fullpath = os.path.join(odb_path, odb_filename)

    # Open the ODB file
    o2 = session.openOdb(name=odb_fullpath)
    odb_basename = os.path.splitext(odb_filename)[0]  # Get the base name without extension

    # Set up the viewport
    session.Viewport(name='Viewport: 1', origin=(0.0, 0.0), width=162.0, height=189.25)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].makeCurrent()
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].maximize()
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=o2)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.display.setValues(plotState=(CONTOURS_ON_DEF, ))

    # Function to export field report
    def export_field_report(surface_sets, report_filename):
        leaf = dgo.LeafFromSurfaceSets(surfaceSets=surface_sets)
        session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.displayGroup.replace(leaf=leaf)
        odb = session.odbs[odb_fullpath]
        create_folder_if_not_exists(os.path.join(odb_path, odb_basename))
        report_file_path = os.path.join(odb_path, odb_basename, report_filename)
        session.writeFieldReport(fileName=report_file_path, append=OFF, sortItem='Node Label', odb=odb, step=5, frame=9,
                                 outputPosition=NODAL, variable=(('COORD', NODAL, ((COMPONENT, 'COOR1'), (COMPONENT, 'COOR2'), (COMPONENT, 'COOR3'), )), ),
                                 stepFrame=SPECIFY)

    # Export field reports for different surface sets
    export_field_report(("Bottom surf of stencil", ), 'Stencil-last-INC.rpt')
    export_field_report(("PREPREG-UPPER", ), 'Board-last-INC.rpt')
    export_field_report(("Upper surf of stencil", ), 'Upper-Surf-Stencil-last-INC.rpt')
```

I have imported this code in chatgpt but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: use vs code auto-formatting extension

Comment: could you post the exact error you are getting? if there are indentation errors you should get a message with the exact line of the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try removing line breaks in the for loop (there should be no line breaks in the looping statements). Define the export_field_report function before loop.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to retype everything again yourself or run the program and indent the line nicely where you are getting the error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).